# rewrite url from subdirectory to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to redirect the url using .htaccess?

Actual url is `www.mywebsite.com/index.php/user/john`

is need to convert as `john.mywebsite.com/`

Comment: look up; look right; find the search option!

Comment: Try googling it, and make an attempt.  Then post your attempt if it doesn't work. This isn't a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/(.*) $2.mywebsite.com/
```

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. but here john is dynamic text. so how i can handle in htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

If you have wildcard Dns, contact your host provider/adminisrator. And request to the line 
*.yourdomain.com on server configuration file.

You can write your self on your htaccess file as following,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.yourdomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path_to_your_site/subdoamin.php?url=%1
```